# How to return multiple values in a single row based on the criteria in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I have two columns “Fruits” and “Color”, I intend to first filter the color and return the multiple values in a single cell based on the filtered unique color. I am using Google Sheet; I hope it is possible with it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and there are several ways to do this. One of them is to use QUERY and JOIN built-in functions. Assume that the Fruit and Color columns are Columns A and B respectively, the following formula will return `Apple | Cherry | Tomato` :

```
=JOIN(" | ",QUERY(A:B,"SELECT A WHERE B = 'Red'",1)
```

'Red' is a literal. If you want to replace it by the C2 value, then use the following

```
=JOIN(" | ",QUERY(A:B,"SELECT A WHERE B = '"&C2&"'",1))
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have applied the formula but I think something is missing, results are not appearing as required. Can you please review and suggest here on Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X9f-npytQ8EEvNe49fLIqHa5Xe30d9MoZCb_Mlrp_EE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks for the solution, one more thing and how can I get the unique color thru formula in column 'C' please.

Comment: That looks to be a follow up question. Please post as a new question.